# Javascript function

Tags: javascript

**This is my first question at stackoverflow, i hope someone can help me**

```
var filters = {
  all: function (todos) {
    return todos
  },
  active: function (todos) {
    return todos.filter(function (todo) {
      return !todo.completed
    })
  },
  completed: function (todos) {
    return todos.filter(function (todo) {
      return todo.completed
    })
  }
}

filteredTodos: function () {
      return filters[this.visibility](this.todos)
    },
```

Why can this "filters [this.visibility]（this.todos）" use
I used to be alert () so
Not used alert [] () like this
please help me

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear - what exactly are you asking?

Comment: `filters[this.visibility]` is not a function call, it's a property being accessed using [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) - the resulting property _is_ a function, hence the `(this.todos)` invocation at the end

Comment: *"How do that "filters[this.visibility] (this.todos) use I used to be alert() so NOT []{}(). "*  English please.

Comment: @zer00ne take it easy, obviously OP is a non-native speaker...

Comment: Reading the first sentence indicates OP has a grasp of the English language. @ironicaldiction I said please, I did not vote to close this question, nor have I downvoted it, so what else do you think I could do to "take it easy?" Should I edit the last sentence for OP,? I would gladly do it if what was written had any coherence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filters[this.visibility](this.todos)` means that `filters[this.visibility]` evaluates to a function.

E.g. if `this.visibility = "all"` then `filters[this.visibility]` means `filters["all"]`. You then call that function with the argument `this.todos`. It's equivalent to writing

```
filters.all(this.todos)
```

but it allows the function to be selected dynamically based on `this.visibility`.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, I want to understand